# How to foreach iterate razor item that contain collection list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach

How to iterate this Result list item in razor?

My Controller :

```
ViewBag.DataGrid = lst. GroupBy(x=> new { x.PosisiJabatanId, x.AplikasiId}, (key, group) => new 
                                         {
                                             Key1 = key.PosisiJabatanId,
                                             Key2 = key.AplikasiId,
                                             Result = group.ToList() 
                                         });
```

My Razor View :

```
@foreach (var item in @ViewBag.DataGrid)
            {
                @:<tr>
                    <td>@i</td>
                    <td>@item.Result.Organisasi</td>
                    <td>@item.Result.NamaAplikasi</td>
                    <td>@item.Result.Unit</td>
                    <td>@item.Result.PosisiJabatanId</td>

                i = i + 1;
                @:</tr>
            }
```

But **'object' does not contain a definition for 'Result'**

Comment: have you chacked, your result containing value or not?, because your loop is on other variable, so there may be chance that your result variable is null.

Comment: @Vishalmodi sorry my question has been edited for the different variable. When debugging, my ```item``` already contain value

Comment: Try debugging inside the `foreach` by setting a breakpoint, or by explicitly calling `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` in the loop body. You can then inspect `item`. Also:  `Result` is a ***`List<T>`*** and even after you found how to access `Result`, I expect that expressions such as `Result.Unit` will still need to be changed.

Comment: Thankyou @PeterB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are facing this issue because you are trying to use for each loop on anonymous object.
so first you need to get value from it like below. and then you need to eterat for each loop on it.

```
 @foreach (var item in @ViewBag.DataGrid)
    {
        <tr>
            @{
                var val = item.GetType()
                .GetProperty("Result")
                .GetValue(item);

                foreach (var result in val)
                {
                    <td>@result.Organisasi</td>
                    <td>@result.NamaAplikasi</td>
                    <td>@result.Unit</td>
                    <td>@result.PosisiJabatanId</td>
                }
            }
        </tr>
    }
```